# how to add a sibling component to a jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, html, css

Using the idea illustrated in this example [datepicker](https://codepen.io/dbellotti/pen/ZYgwYW), how to add the header component(the header in blue color) beside the datepicker instead of being on top?  I tried adding this code to make it inline instead of block but it did not work as expected. The datepicker is distorted. The arrows should stay on top of the calendar and the close /ok buttons at the bottom.  Only the new component is added beside the datepicker. The arrows, the calendar and the buttons are block.

```
if(window.innerHeight<window.innerWidth){
    (jQuery)(".ui-datepicker").css('display', 'flex');
    (jQuery)(".ui-datepicker").css('align-items', 'flex-start');
     (jQuery)(".ui-datepicker").prepend(headerHtml);
}
```

Comment: So you want the blue box always at the sides?

Comment: yes, that is the idea when screen orientation is landscape.

Comment: What if you give these styles `.ui-datepicker-material-header {position: absolute; right: -325px; height: 350px;}`

Comment: sorry, i tried your suggestion but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, check the answer below. Hope that explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Apply these styles on on `.ui-datepicker-material-header` when you switch to landscape mode.

```
.ui-datepicker-material-header{
    position: absolute;
    right: -325px;
    height: 350px;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks i got your idea, it works. i will try to check this one still on how it works in responsive mode.